# Monitor shows up as unknown on a Dell D630

Tags: nvidia, graphics

Am a newbie on ubuntu and have tried to get my graphics working with ubuntu oneiric without success. My Monitor is Unknown I have installed all Ubuntu preffered drivers but nothing has changed yet.
My Video player has green pictures
My monitor unknown
compiz effects dont work

my specs are;
nVIDIA Quadro NVS 135M

I have also tried to install manually the .run drivers from nVIDIA without success.

Answer (score 1):

My dad's got the same laptop.

Just install the NVidia driver the "Additional hardware drivers" dialog recommends you. After that, search in teh dash for `NVidia` and something like `NVidia X configuration utility` should pop up. Open it.

- [How do I install additional drivers?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47506/how-do-i-install-a-graphics-or-wireless-card-driver)

When you install the NVidia drivers on Ubuntu, you've got to use the tool just mentioned to configure your monitors, not the one included by default.